# Prevent Safari from loading cached version of page

Tags: html, web-applications, safari, meta

I have a very cool animation heavy website that I built for a very artsy client. The site looks great and runs amazing in every browser I've tested it on but safari. The problem is that after you click on a link, all the other elements on the page animate off in 300ms and then the page redirects to the next page.

The problem in safari is that when someone hits the back button, they get returned to a blank page because everything animated off of it. Safari doesn't know to restart all my page scripts from the beginning since it's just loading the cached page from it's memory. Is there an easy way, like a meta tag or other header I can use to force pages to reload it?

Comment: Have a look here https://coderwall.com/p/ndecha

Comment: @AntarrByrd Your link no longer works. Could you post a new link for the rest of us who are coming in late?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

That usually works on my sites to ensure content is loaded freshly.